# Condition coverage on switch statement

Tags: java, sonarqube

When I run coverage on my code below:

```
  private static String mapMyVal(String val) {
    switch (val) {
      case "foo":
        return "FOO_FOO";
      case "bar":
        return "BARR";
      default:
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
  }
```

I see "8 out of 10 conditions covered" when I run my unit tests on this with coverage. However I see all three lines being covered inside the statement.

Since there are no other conditions than "foo", "bar" and everything else, what are those missing two conditions?

Comment: What if `val` is `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one possible case not covered.  The input `val` might be `null`.  In that case, your `switch` statement would throw a `NullPointerException`.  To remedy this, you could add null check to the start of the method.

```
private static String mapMyVal(String val) {
    switch (val) {
        case "foo":
            return "FOO_FOO";
        case "bar":
            return "BARR";
        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nexevis You're right, and I retract what I wrote initially.  But the `null` input edge case should be a concern.

Comment: Good point. In my use case I am handling it before calling this method though e.g. null values never reach the method. Should coverage still consider `null` as a possible value?

Answer (score 1):

There was already someone asking nearly the same question. Overall it turned out that going for 100% of unittest for a switch-case might be pure luck because of the way that java is handling the switch-case. See here [eclemma branch coverage for switch: 7 of 19 missed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013717/eclemma-branch-coverage-for-switch-7-of-19-missed)

Comment: But those answers are from 2015. Surely issues with bytecode inspection that are described there were addressed over the last four years?

Comment: Actually there is an blogentry in the web from the 14 Jan 2019 in which my linked answer is used as a resource. The author gets the same problem/result as the one I mentioned.